# how to rotate a "triangle down" to a "triangle up" using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the following triangle [image: triangle down]

created by the following css:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;

}
```

html:

```
<div class=triangle></div>
```

when i click on the triangle i want it to rotate and become a triangle facing up.Can you guide me on how to achieve this?

this the code tried for triangle up

```
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

im not sure how to get it to rotate when triangle down is clicked to triangle up,and then when triangle up is clicked it must rotate back to triangle down

Comment: if you want to try : https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/cd9grjsb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can use the follwing snippet using css transition ,by toggling a css  class :

```js
$(".triangle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up");

})
```

```css
body {
  margin:20px;
}
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;
    transition: .5s ease;

}

.triangle-up {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin: 50% 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: This works great,the only problem i am having is that when i click it the first time it does nothing,but on the second click then it changes,so i have to do like a double click for it to move,do you have any idea why it would do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toggleClass()` and `transform` to rotate the arrow

```js
$(".triangle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("triangle-up");

})
```

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 80px solid red;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.triangle-up {
 transform:rotateX(180deg);
 margin-top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't consider the "flip" effect on the `transform` rule, this might actually work better for the OP than the typical "rotation".

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to toggle between the two Classes (if no animation is required):

```js
$('.triangle,.triangle-up').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("triangle triangle-up");
});
```

```css
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;

}
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=triangle></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to toggle this class with some JavaScript:

```js
var triangle = document.querySelector('.triangle');

triangle.addEventListener('click', function(){
triangle.classList.toggle('triangle-up')
});
```

```css
.triangle {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
margin-left: -10px;
}

.triangle-up {
transform: rotate(180deg);
border-top: 10px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

This toggles between up and down when the arrow is clicked.

If you've got multiple arrows then just change the JS to:

```
var triangle = document.querySelectorAll('.triangle');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(triangle, function(el, i){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    el.classList.toggle('triangle-up');
  });
});
```

Comment: I preferred the previous version, it would have been much easier to add an animation there, by just adding something like  `transition: transform .3s linear;` to `.triangle`

Comment: @Pevara I agree, so I've changed it back. I've added the JS for multiple class instances too.

Comment: Note that if the triangle you want to rotate is in a span (i.e. an inline element) it will need to become a block, i.e. `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider toggling between specified classes, as demonstrated in the embedded code snippet below.

**jQuery `.toggleClass()` method:**

```js
jQuery('.triangle').on('click', function(){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('triangle triangle-up');
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
}

.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;

}

.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=triangle></div>
```

Alternatively, you could adjust the specified styles for the class `.triangle-up` to rotate the element (with a `transform` rule declared), instead of redefining borders, then only toggle this class. With the addition of a declared `transition` rule, this will allow the element in question to animate when toggling between classes.

**jQuery `.toggleClass()` method (transition animation demonstration):**

```js
jQuery('.triangle').on('click', function(){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('triangle-up');
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
}

.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;
    transition: .5s; /* required for animation effect */
}

.triangle-up {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=triangle></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by using .hasClass() and .addClass() method in jQuery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.triangle').click(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).hasClass('triangle-up')){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('triangle-up');
   }else{
    jQuery(this).addClass('triangle-up');
   }
       
  });
 });
```

```css
    .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #cecece;
    margin-left: -10px;
    }

    .triangle-up{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=triangle></div>
```